Swiper Laravel 9 VueJs 3
I'm trying to do a swiper using laravel api vue js composition api, the swiper doesn't work, it was working at first with the template(statically using the swiper code in main.js), but when I added some vueJs code, it stops
template.blade.php:
    <div id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>   
   </div>

  </main><!-- End #main -->

I've imported there all css and js files that came with the template
Index.vue :
<template>
...
     <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

       <div class="section-title">
         <h2>Actualités</h2>
         <p>Dernières Actualités</p>
         <router-link :to="{ name: 'Actualites' }" > Actualites view</router-link>

       </div>

     </div>
     <section id="testimonials" class="testimonials">
       <div class="container" data-aos="zoom-in">
         <div class="testimonials-slider swiper" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
           <div class="swiper-wrapper">
             <div class="swiper-slide" v-for="actualite in actualites" 
               :key="actualite.id">
               <div class="testimonial-item" v-if="actualite.images.length > 0">
                 <img :src="'/storage/' + actualite.images[0].url" 
                 :alt="actualite.images[0].caption" class="testimonial-img">
                 <h3>{{ actualite.title }} Actualité de 05/04/2024</h3>
                 <br>
                 <p>
                   <h2>
                     <i class="bx bxs-quote-alt-left quote-icon-left"></i>
                     {{ actualite.content }}
                     <i class="bx bxs-quote-alt-right quote-icon-right"></i>
                   </h2>
                   <h4>Lire plus</h4>
                 </p>
               </div>
             </div><!-- End testimonial item -->
           </div>
           <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </section>
</template>   

<script>
 import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
 import Swiper from 'swiper';
 import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
 import useActualites from '../composition-api/useActualites';
 import HeaderIndex from './HeaderIndex.vue';

 export default {
   name: 'Index',
   components: {
     HeaderIndex
   },
   setup() {
     const { actualites, fetchActualites } = useActualites();

     // Chargement des actualités lors de la création du composant
     onMounted(() => {
       fetchActualites();

      

       // Initialisation de Swiper pour testimonials-slider
       new Swiper('.testimonials-slider', {
         speed: 600,
         loop: true,
         autoplay: {
           delay: 5000,
           disableOnInteraction: false
         },
         slidesPerView: 'auto',
         pagination: {
           el: '.swiper-pagination',
           type: 'bullets',
           clickable: true
         }
       });
     });

     return { actualites, fetchActualites };
   }
 }
</script>


And style.css:
.testimonials .swiper-pagination {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.testimonials .swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.testimonials .swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background-color: #ffc451;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .testimonials {
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .testimonials .testimonial-item p {
    width: 80%;
  }

useActualites.js:
import { ref } from "vue";

export default function useActualites() {


   
    const errors = ref({});
    const generalError = ref(null);

    const actualites = ref([]);
   
    //Home
    const fetchActualites = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/actualites'); 
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to fetch actualites');
            }
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data)

            actualites.value = data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching actualites:', error);
        }
    };

    return { errors, generalError, actualites, fetchActualites };
}


All is good except the Swiper Part, it doesn't work, it displays juste the first actualité, knowing that the api is just fine.

The closing script tag should be </script>, not <script/>

typo, i ve already fixed it
